# running sbt command from ansible shell

Tags: sbt, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run a sbt command using ansible's shell command as follows from the main.yml in a role's task directory:

```
- shell: ./sbt clean reload compile
```

I have also tried the following:

```
- shell: /usr/sbin/sbt clean reload compile
```

Neither command works.  The output from **which sbt** is

```
/usr/bin/sbt
```

The error message I get from ansible is:

```
fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/usr/bin/sbt clean reload compile", "delta": "0:00:00.062588", "end": "2016-10-04 21:36:26.883947", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2016-10-04 21:36:26.821359", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/sbt: not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Comment: I had to use local_action before shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use local_action before using the shell command (the command was running on the remote machine, not the local one previously):

```
- local_action: shell /usr/bin/sbt clean reload compile
```